# run tests for all go modules in subfolders

Tags: go

I've created the following directory tree with utilities to work with git.

```
./git-logbranch/git-logbranch_test.go
./git-logbranch/git-logbranch.go
./git-logbranch/go.mod
./git-issue/git-issue_test.go
./git-issue/go.mod
./git-issue/git-issue.go
./main.go
./go.mod
```

I've read several posts that say './...' will automatically run tests in all sub-folders, but it in fact does not do so.  This is what I'm running and the output I get:

```
$ go test ./...
?       main    [no test files]
```

Here's some example output from the subfolders. As you can see, the individual tests work:

```
$ go test ./...
ok      git_logbranch   0.001s

$ go test ./...
ok      git_issue   (cached)
```

Any ideas on how to run all these tests at once?

Comment: Two too many go.mod files, to me it seems. Are these 3 separate projects? If just 1, keep the root go.mod, ditch the rest, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Removing the go modules makes `go test ./...` find all the tests. Could you post that as an answer?  It would be good if you get into more detail though.  Some ideas would be proper go module conventions.  Maybe why go test can't cross the module boundary, and or how it can if you need modules, etc.  Those would all be relevant to the question, and would inform other readers and myself a little bit more about proper go conventions.  I'd be happy to accept it as an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-define-a-module

> When executed from the root directory of a module, the `./...` pattern
> matches all the packages **within the current module**.

<sup>(note: it does not say "within the current *directory*")</sup>

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Defining_a_module

> The module is the set of all Go packages in the module root and its
> subdirectories, **but excluding subtrees with their own go.mod files**.